# Can i use MOveIt package in ROS without closed loop motor control?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two DC Servo motors with step and direction pins. But i dont have any feedback from the motor. I had read earlier that moveIt requires closed loop feedback control for operation.
[Specifications of motor](http://www.robokits.co.in/documentation/RMCS225x_DCServo_Driver.pdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299678/can-i-use-moveit-package-in-ros-without-closed-loop-motor-control?/) by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-08-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-05**:\

> I had read earlier that moveIt requires closed loop feedback control for operation

could you please provide a link to where you read this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is correct that MoveIt! expects to retrieve joint state information, otherwise it would not be possible to know the state the robot is in. This information normally is provided by encoders built into arm joints and then published to ROS on the `/joint_states` topic. If you don't have encoders on your motors you can always fake sensing joint positions by publishing the commanded joint positions to `/joint_states`, faking that they have been measured. Depending on your setup this can either work reasonably well (i.e. arm moves slow, your motor are tracking commanded values very well), or utterly fail (i.e. fast motions, significant differences between commanded and actually executed motions).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2